# How to change IEnumerable<byte> to String

Tags: c#

I have the following simplified function:

```
private IEnumerable<byte> Encode(IEnumerable<byte> Input)
{
   computation();
   return result;
}
```

The Buffer:

```
 byte[] BufferHex = {0x00};
 IEnumerable<byte> result1;
 richtext.AppendText(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result1));
```

The error is at the last line saying: Conversion IEnumerable to byte[] not possible.

I have tried several things but still no success. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

As it says it is expecting a `byte[]` as parameter, so you need to convert your `IEnumerable<byte>` to a `byte[]`, you can do this using [ToArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
richtext.AppendText(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result1.ToArray()));
```

Comment: That was quick,Thank you, the error does go away but I dont get any usable data. I suppose the function somehow only returns crap data.

Answer (score 3):

[`Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_Encoding_GetString_System_Byte___)  expects a parameter of type `byte[]`, not `IEnumerable<byte>`. So simply change that line to

```
richtext.AppendText(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result1.ToArray()));
```

[`ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) is a LINQ extension that converts an `IEnumerable<T>` into a `T[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be suitable for your case, but you can use `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[] bytes)` and don't forget to call `ToArray()`, on your enumerable